# Disabling Fused Multiply-Add in CUDA under Visual Studio 2010

Tags: cuda

I would like to compile a CUDA code with Fused Multiply-Add (FMA) operations disabled. I'm then using

```
Project -> Properties -> CUDA C/C++ -> Host -> Additional Compiler Options
```

and typing

```
-fdma=false
```

in the Additional Compiler Options line. Is that effective in disabling FMAs?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please see [Options for Steering CUDA Compilation](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-compiler-driver-nvcc/index.html#options-for-steering-cuda-compilation). You have a typo in your parameter but otherwise you are correct.

> -fmad : Enables (disables) the contraction of floating-point multiplies and adds/subtracts into floating-point multiply-add operations (FMAD, FFMA, or DFMA). The default is -fmad=true.